# What is the * in vectors?

Tags: c, vector

I'm doing my homework about vectors and emerged me a question about the * behind de vector name. What does it mean? and what this do?
If i remove this, my code show a problem ("Format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double' "). thanks for the help, and sorry by the bad english.

´´´

```
float *numbers[] = {}, sum;

for (int i = 0; i <= quant; i++){
    printf("%dº number\n", i);
    scanf("%f", numbers[i]);
    for(int y = 0; y <= i; y++){
        sum = sum +  numbers[y];
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation on `scanf`.

Comment: Note that in `scanf("%f", numbers[i]);` the array of pointers has no elements, and MSVC throws a compiler error anyway. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: hahaha, i forgot it, that is the problem on my code, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` in C/C++ means a pointer. A pointer is the address of some data, in this case the address of a float. `numbers` is an array of pointers to floats. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: oh, thanks. this is a second problem in my code, i didn't need the adress of a variable on vector, but your value.. Thanks!!!